Counting no. of possible solutions of linear equation modulo a prime?
The original question is from the Algorithms book, CLRS. After simplification, the question reduces to this pure math problem, which I am finding difficult - I feel as if there is some gap in my knowledge of modulo arithmetic.
Let $\mathbb{Z}_p = \{0 ,1, ... p-1 \}$, where $p$ is some prime. Then for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$, prove/disprove that for any $\vec{a} \in \mathbb{Z}_p^n \setminus \vec{0}$, the total number of solutions of $$\vec{x} \cdot \vec{a} \equiv 0 \mod p$$ for $\vec{x} \in \mathbb{Z}_p^n$ is atmost $\le p^{n-1}$.
Note that the $\cdot$ means vector dot product. I am absolutely clueless how to solve this (btw I feel the statement is true) - is there some theory on system of linear equations in modulo $p$ which I can leverage here?

Well, if $\vec a\neq \vec 0$ then at least one component of $\vec a$ is non-zero, so...

I have edited the comment to focus more on the point.

The comment is confusing now - I can see its true, but cant see the connection to how it helps to solve the problem.

Say $\vec a = (1, 0, \cdots, 0)$.  What is the count in that case?

In that case, 1. Not sure how that helps for $\vec{a}$ which has many non-zero coordinates.

The answer is not $1$ in that case.

Oh my bad, I see it would be $p^{n-1}$ because of the coordinates which dont contribute to the dot product.

Right.  Now argue that this is the most extreme case possible.

Was able to prove that. But I found that in every case the no. of solutions is EXACTLY $p^{n-1}$ (and never strictly less) - in your terminology, every case is the most extreme one. My proof: Let $a_1x_1 + .. a_tx_t = 0$ mod p where all $a_i's$ are non-zero. Then for any of the $p^{t-1}$ possible values of $(x_2, x_3, .. x_t)$ there will always exist a unique value of $x_1$ as $p$ is prime given by $a_1^{-1}( -a_2x_2 - .. a_tx_t  )$ mod p.

Well, that only looks at the case where all the entries are non-zero, but sure.  Geometrically, the multiples of $\vec a$ are a one dimensional subspace, and the orthogonal space has dimension $n-1$.  That's all you need.
